# Unable to send SMS using PHP via malert.in gateway

Tags: php

I am using malert.in as sms gateway. I want to send the details the user entered, but in place of name $name is sent.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<html>
   <body>
    <form action='sms.php' method='post'>
        <div>
            <label for='name'>Name</label>
            <input type='text' name='name' id='name'/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for='pnr'>Pnr</label>
            <input type='text' name='pnr' id='pnr'/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type='submit' name='send' value='send'/>
        </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $pnr = $_POST['pnr'];

    header('Location:http://malert.in/new/api/api_http.php?username=uname&password=pass&senderid=Alerts&to=7098765438,9454321121&text=$name%20$pnr%20success&route=Transaction&type=text&datetime=2015-01-23%2015%3A15%3A14');
}
?
```

Where is the mistake? I checked everything.

Comment: DO NOT USE THAT !!! You give everyone who views your page the password. Use Curl instead

Comment: what is not working?  get any error message?

Comment: as the the actual question, could you post the docs you are working to ? Its hard to say without knowing their API

Comment: incorrect password or username just contact the service provider ...use curl instead with proper credential .or contact service provider

Comment: EVERYTHING WORKS FINE...even i got the message but the problem is that instead of contents of variable $name i get $name as it is printed.

Comment: this username and pass is just for example i have not mentioned the actual one

Comment: Don't use header... or people use your site to send some sms to their friends for free.

(The solution for your problem should be to use double quotes instead of single quotes in the header to parse the variable into the string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are not evaluated in single quotes. You need to either use double quotes, or add the individual string pieces together:

```
header('Location: ...&text='.$name.'%20$pnr%20success&route=Tra...');
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables are not expanded inside single quoted strings such as `'text=$name'`, but only inside double quoted strings like `"text=$name"`. Additionally, if you need to append the string to a URL, you need to also escape it appropriately with [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode). You could do something like:

```
header('Location:' .
  'http://malert.in/new/api/api_http.php' .
    '?username=uname' .
    '&password=pass' .
    '&senderid=Alerts' .
    '&to=7098765438,9454321121' .
    '&text=' . urlencode("$name $pnr success") .
    '&route=Transaction' .
    '&type=text' .
    '&datetime=' . urlencode('2015-01-23 15:15:14'));
```